# Category that contains: "renaissance painters", "Austrian economists", "beat poets"

Tags: american-english, collective-nouns, academia

I'm wondering if there's a proper term for a kind of collective noun that specifies a group of individuals of "great historical significance". I'm looking particularly for a kind of class that includes the following groups of nouns:

"renaissance painters", "Austrian economists", "beat poets"

"Schools of thought" is the best I can come up with, as in the hierarchy represented in [this Wikipedia branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Schools_of_thought), but that doesn't return the kind of search results I'm after. (I'm really looking for a large digital representation of these kinds of nouns, so if others know of that kind of resource, that's doubly helpful!)

How would others typify these collective nouns?

Comment: ['renowned authors' like Dan Brown?](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/myl/languagelog/archives/001628.html)

Comment: You might be better referring to the associated _movements_.

Comment: *Aesthetics*? From Wikipedia: "a branch of philosophy dealing with the nature of art, beauty, and taste, with the creation and appreciation of beauty.... More broadly, scholars in the field define aesthetics as 'critical reflection on art, culture and nature.' In modern English, the term aesthetic can also refer to a set of principles underlying the works of a particular art movement or theory: one speaks, for example, of the Cubist aesthetic."

Comment: What would be wrong with '(groups of) historical figures', please?

The differences among 'renaissance painters', 'Austrian economists' and 'beat poets' strike me as so overwhelmingly much greater than any meaningful similarity, they might as well be 'flockers together' let alone 'birds of a feather.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a true "collective noun" that could be consistently used to mean "a group of painters" or the like, though there are two words that might partially satisfy this question.

"School" is a word used to describe a group of artists, writers, or philosophers who share a common theme to their work, be it a common teacher (or a university or region) or a distinctive style:  "The Impressionist school" or "the Berlin school", e.g.  "Movement" is also sometimes used:  "the Beat Movement started with Kerouac."

I wouldn't call either of them a "collective noun" in the same way you would see a "gaggle of children" or a "herd of cows."  And I specifically would not say "the Renaissance school of painters"; that is far too broad.

There are various web sites that purport to have large lists of "collective nouns" but many of the purported examples on them strike me as apocryphal and you'd rely on them at the risk of sounding a bit stilted (for instance, this one: http://www.rinkworks.com/words/collective.shtml).  A bit of Googling found another one where most of them seem to make sense: http://www.ojohaven.com/collectives/

Answer (score 0):

I thought of 2:
Preeminents
Paramounts
In context, "the preeminents of the counter-culture revolution" or "a paramountcy of Renaissance painters". I think the phrasing has merit, i.e., you say "the [collective-noun] of the >subject<", rather than "a [collective-noun] of >objects<".
And there's always the collective *adjective*, for example, "paramount group of Austrian economists" :)

Answer (score 0):

"Leading lights" is  a phrase sometimes used to describe the most prominent and influential members of a group.

> The leading lights of Austrian economics
>
> The leading lights of renaissance painting
>
> The leading lights of beat poetry.